# How can I only take the regex without using re.split()?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I'm sorry for the title, I don't know how to ask this properly.

There's an HTML file I want to parse, using python2.7's `re` library. I know that I should use BeautifulSoup or stuff like that for parsing, but that doesn't really matter here.

There's a part in this HTML file: `<br>(40%)</TD>`. In this example, the number (here, it's `40`) changes every now and then.

I want to use this number as a variable. To get that done, I'm using `re.split()` to split off everything preceding `40` and everything following `40` :

```
html = getHtmlTextFromWebsite()
very_important_number = int(re.split("%\)</TD>", (re.split("<br>\(", html))[1])[0])
```

I find this a very cumbersome way to do this and I'm wondering whether there are better ways.

Comment: Why regex? In your case you can just use `str.strip()` method.

Comment: Regex stars don't shine for parsing HTML. Better use a DOM parser library. BeautifulSoup ( http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/ ) comes to my mind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you need is to have the number, you should use the [match](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#performing-matches) (first match) or finditer (all matches) function instead.

```
import re
p = re.compile("<br>\((\d+%)\)<\/TD>", re.IGNORECASE)
for m in p.finditer(html_code):
    print m.start(), m.group()
```

It will also give you the position of each number found.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the regex you asked, but it strips everything before and after the number:

```
very_important_number = int(html.strip("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ%()<>br/"))
```

For regex, you can use the [`re.match` method](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/re.html#re.match).

Hope this helps!

Comment: That will destroy everything except the first occurence of an int. Returning only that first occurence.

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
r = re.compile(r'<br>\((\d+)%\)</TD>', re.I)
m = r.search(text)
print m.group(1)
```

Here you can [search](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/re.html#re.RegexObject.search) for this exact pattern throughout the text and get it along with its "environment" (the match). From the match, you now extract the group #1 (the `()` enclosed part).

You as well can [search without a compiled re object](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/re.html#re.search):

```
m = re.search(r'<br>\((\d+)%\)</TD>', text, re.I)
print m.group(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

```
import re
html = getHtmlTextFromWebsite()
number = re.findall(r'<br>(.*?)%</br>', html)
```

to print the number:

```
print number[0]
```

which prints `40` with the example text.